# CanCan 2.0 + Paperclip expiring_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, cancan

I set some files using Paperclip `expiring_url`. Those are working fine.

I try using CanCan 2.0 to allow `expiring_url` only to signed members using the following code

```
# /app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new  # guest user
    can :read, :movies
    cannot :read, :movies, :expiring_url

    if user.persisted?
      can :read, :movies, :expiring_url
    end

  end
end
```

My `MoviesController.rb` has `load_and_authorize_resource` still all users are being able to download the movie.

`expiring_url` is not an attribute of `Movie` and I can see that is the reason why is not working. I'm not sure how can specify the paperclip expiring_url object associated to this in order to make it work.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Cancan apparently requires the conditions to be actual database columns, according to the statement on [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) page:

> It is important to only use database columns for these conditions

This isn't a limitation in paperclip, it's cancan (which I love quite a bit, don't get me wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I use CanCan 1.6.x, but under **Defining Abilities** in the [2.0 docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/tree/2.0),  Ryan says

> The current_user is passed in allowing you to define permissions based on user attributes.

so if you have a current_user would not something like below work for you?

```
if user
  can :read, :movies, :expiring_url
else
  can :read, :movies
end
```

---

Can you provide more info about what "expiring_url" is? I just realized the above probably won't work for you either since **expiring_url** doesn't sound like a model.